What is special valuation ring?
I'm reading Nagata's paper On the theory of henselian rings.
The term "special valuation ring" appears several times in this paper, but I cannot find its definition in this paper. I haven't found it anywhere else online either.


Could it be that the field of fraction is "relatively complete"? That seems to be the context of citation 9 in your article, and I notice that it says Ostrowski first defined such fields in a citation common to both papers (citation 7 in your paper).
